# perl6/rakudo: Problem with writing on the loop-variable

Tags: for-loop, raku, read-write, rakudo-star

```
#!perl6
use v6;

my $longest = 3;
my @list = <a b c d e f>;

for @list -> $element is rw {
    $element = sprintf "%*.*s", $longest, $longest, $element;
    $element.say;
}
```

This works. But in the second and third I get an error-message. How could I make them work?

```
#!perl6
use v6;

my $longest = 3;
my @list = <a b c d e f>;

for @list <-> $element {
    $element = sprintf "%*.*s", $longest, $longest, $element;
    $element.say;
}

# ===SORRY!===
# Missing block at line 11, near ""
```

.

```
#!perl6
use v6;

my $longest = 3;
my $list = <a b c d e f>;

for $list.list -> $element is rw {
    $element = sprintf "%*.*s", $longest, $longest, $element;
    $element.say;
}

# Cannot modify readonly value
#   in '&infix:<=>' at line 1
#   in <anon> at line 8:./perl5.pl
#   in main program body at line 1
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Regarding your second example

The `<->` may not have worked in the Rakudo Perl you used, but it has been fixed in more recent versions. (It had to do with a deep parsing issue that required a better longest-token-matching algorithm than we had at that time.)

### Regarding your third example

The statement

```
my $list = <a b c d e f>;
```

creates `$list` as a `Seq` data type, and `Seq` elements are considered to be immutable.  What you really want is for `$list` to become an `Array`, as in:

```
my $list = [<a b c d e f>];
```

With that in place, the last example works as expected:

```
pmichaud@orange:~/rakudo$ cat x.p6
#!perl6
use v6;

my $longest = 3;
my $list = [<a b c d e f>];

for $list.list -> $element is rw {
    $element = sprintf "%*.*s", $longest, $longest, $element;
    $element.say;
}

pmichaud@orange:~/rakudo$ ./perl6 x.p6
  a
  b
  c
  d
  e
  f
pmichaud@orange:~/rakudo$
```

Hope this helps!

Pm